# Understanding 4D Gauge Fields in Compactified String Theory

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, spacetime-dimensions, branes, compactification

**Question:**

I have a conceptual question regarding $4$-dimensional compactifications in string theory. For example, if we consider *flat* $10$-dimensional space with D$6$-branes, we obtain $7$-dimensional gauge fields from strings attached to such a brane living in the $6+1$-dimensional world volume of the D-brane.

Now, if we use *compactification* to obtain a 4-dimensional theory, the D6-brane would fill out the $3+1$ spacetime dimensions and wrap a $3$-cycle in the internal compact space. This yields a $4$-dimensional spacetime gauge field. Why is that?

**Possible Explanation:**

In the compactified dimensions, we indeed obtain a $4D$ gauge field living there in the $3+1$-dimensional world volume of the D-brane. However, one might wonder if there are also gauge fields arising in the physical spacetime dimensions. So if the 4d gauge fields arise from the internal space, what happens with the string excitations in the non-compact space.

**Note:** The matter content arises from strings at intersections of D-brane stacks in the internal space. These are already 4-dimensional in the 10-flat dimensions, so it makes sense that in a compactified theory they remain 4-dimensional. We do not get any contribution from the non-compact space since there are no intersections.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0007170 is the best introductory reference on branes in general

Comment: This doesn't provide assistance. It serves as an introduction to a very broad topic, which I'm already well acquainted with. As mentioned in my initial inquiry, my difficulty lies not in technical matters but in conceptual ones.

Comment: Maybe try the section on wrapped D-branes